# spring boot login check implement way

Tags: spring-boot

My way of implementing login check

```
@Configuration
public class ViewControllerImpl implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer(){
        WebMvcConfigurer adapter = new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
                registry.addInterceptor(new InterceptorConfig()).addPathPatterns("/**")
                        .excludePathPatterns("/login", "/", "/session", "/static/**");

            }



     @Override
                public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
                    WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
                }
            };
            return adapter;
        }
    }

public class InterceptorConfig implements HandlerInterceptor
{

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        Object loginStatus = request.getSession().getAttribute("loginStatus");
        if(loginStatus == "success"){
            return true;
        }
        else {
//            request.getRequestDispatcher("login").forward(request, response);
            response.sendRedirect("/login");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

After the username and password are successfully verified，I will store a loginstatus in the session.

if loginstatus is success， it means that you have logged in.

Is this code implementation safe?

Do I need to use spring security?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use Spring Security instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like @m-deinum already said you should really just utilize `Spring-Security`. There is a super quick tutorial on how to do this here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

You will start to learn it with `BasicAuth` and an InMemoryDB for user and password storage. You will end up with an application that returns a status Code `200` for logged in user or a status code `401` for a denied access.

From there on it is easy to extend your application to user user and password stored in a custom db or even OAuth.

Have no fear using it - its easy and fun :)